# How to place the right seams for the UV mapping of a curvy object like this?

Tags: texturing, uv

In the pic is my object, it's basically half a deformed sphere cut in two.

I'm placing seams on an object in order to UV map it and add texture, but I don't understand how to do it properly. I chose the profile where the sphere has been cut, and two diagonals as the seams (you can see them in the pic). But when I use "Unwrap", I have no visible result in the UV/Image editor. I think it may be because I'm not placing the right seams, do you have any ideas on how to do that properly?

Thanks in advance!

[image: This is my object, it's basically the half a deformed sphere cut in two.]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all an expert in unwrapping, but I'd say the trick is not so much in the seam placement, but more in the top geometry of the mesh where all the loops meet.

Make sure you have an **all quads mesh that doesn't end in a triangle fan**.

If you are not sure what I mean, try this:

**1)** Select the top vertex and delete it.

**2)** Select the first open edge loop, extrude it and right click to cancel (leave it in place).

**3)** Scale it to zero to make it meet at the center. 
You may move it slightly up in Z to compensate so it's not perfectly flat.
Make sure you **don't remove doubles so you have a quad's only mesh.**

**4)** Lastly you can use the *Unwrap > Follow Active Quads > Lenght Average* to have an even rectangular unwrap.

Comment: Fun fact: I exported the poligon to another .blend file and now I'm able to unwrap it normally. By the way I see what you're saying. On the top right now I have a "triangle fan", I'm gonna switch it with an all-quads solution!