# single face has whole texture

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

Hello! 
I need some help, I can't figure out why this single face has the whole texture I use for the whole face.
I'm a beginner and this is my first model, so this might be easy to fix, but I can't find any solution that works online.
thanks!

looks fine in editmode

[image]

Comment: Maybe related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52379/apply-the-same-texture-to-multiple-faces. That face could be unwrapped alone from the rest of the mesh hence its scale on the UV map is way big compared to others. You could select it and part of the UV map it belongs to and [stitch](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_editing.html#stitch) them or reunwrap once more with all selected, there might be other ways

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but no, its not way bigger compared to the others, it has the right size and is in the right place. When I re-unwrap it, it's still there

Comment: Did you compare size of the face or size of the UV island on the map? If texture changes its density on the mesh then first thing to edit is UV map. Can you include a screenshot of this face selected and UV editor opened and zoomed in (it's not visible on the shown above). Or you could [upload the file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and paste the link here.